# How front-end router works in a MVC Framework?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, react-router

I cannot fully understand how a single page application can do routing by itself.

Maybe you can see the example [here](http://www.reactrails.com/).

[image: example]

If you click on those links (below the visited, purple color link), the url and the page will be change without reloading. But how to achieve this if the front-end is deployed in a MVC framework?

Isn't that if you visit a url on MVC, it'll will look for the corresponding controller for that url? If that happen, of course the page will be reloaded isn't it? If it using HTML5 History, how can when I revisit the url, the page display the changed state?

Can someone explain how to achieve this with React app that deployed on a MVC framework like Rails? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm more familiar with Angular, but all the `Single Page Applications` (`SPA`) are based on the the same model. You have three layers:

- the `Rails` MVC routing system with its routes and controllers
- the `React` SPA routing system (that also has its own
  routes and controller system)
- the `React` event handling system that, as a javascript framework, among other things, catches mouse clicks in the web application

In your `reactrails` example page, the root of your web site (`/`) is handled by `Rails`, and every other pages (`/*`) are intercepted and handled by the `react` routing system.

So basically, if you have a rails `ApplicationController` you could have a `config/routes.rb` like this:

```
# routes.rb
root 'application#main'
# catch every routes and serve only the Application.main action
match '*path', to: 'application#main'

# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController
    def main
    end
end
```

This will redirect every urls coming to `Rails` (`/this/is/an/example`, `/that/one/is/not/an/example`...) to the `React` router. (Note that you could also have other routes such as `/api/gimme/my/damn/json/data` that will resolve to other controllers and send back `JSON`, `xml`, `html` or any kind of data)

Then, in your html page, `React` intercepts every clicks, on links or buttons, and compare them to its own routes.
If a route match, it will display the correct page via its templating system, (usually loading it by `Ajax` or read it from its cache), and you won't see any page reload. You could say that `react` act has a client-side server.

If you call a url such as `/i/like/flowers`, the route will be first processed by `rails` (`/*`), that will send you an `html` file located at the `/` route, containing your `SPA` app, that will kicks in, analyse the route itself, and show you the correct content from its own templating system.

So to sum up, you have:

```
GET /my/super/react/url
//=> Rails serves `main.html` that includes `react-router`
```

Once `main.html` is loaded, `react-router` looks at its routes components and serve the right template if route exists (`/my/super/react/url`).

You could find more examples in the [react-router documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)

This is the basic scenario, and I'm sure others will complete anything I didn't cover, and add `react` specific samples!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Nicely explained ;)